# Getting a per thread cpu stats

Tags: linux, threads

I'm interested in the current usage of cpu - precisely cpu% and wait% - for each thread in a specific application. Is it possible to get that information from somewhere?

I know that `top` can split information per real thread (ones with pid), but it doesn't show the system/user/wait cpu usage split for each of them. I would also like some way to log that info. Do you know any apps (or apis) that can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd look into [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/).  This tool will certainly give you what you want.  There is [this](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/profiling/thread-times.stp) example of profiling threads; don't know if it has all you want, but you could modify it so that it does.

Answer (score 24):

```
top -H -p pid
```

hope it can help

Answer (score 14):

Percent of cpu usage per thread you can get with `ps` command:

```
 ps -emo %cpu,pid,user,args
```

The way it is calculated is described in [`ps manpage`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps):

> Currently, it is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio),
>                       expressed as a percentage.

Comment: I'm really interested in both cpu time and io-wait time. ps can't handle the second one unfortunately.

Comment: note to self: replace -e by -C java and pid by spid for thread Ids in java app

Comment: greater note to self: `ps -To pcpu,tid -C java | sort -r -k1 | more` for hog threads in a java app. `ps --sort=pcpu` achieves nothing; better rely on shell for the sorting part.

Comment: Very useful @kellogs, thanks. I would add `-n` or `-g` to sort, so that "10" shows up above "2", for example.

Comment: *...it is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running...* IMHO usually we need to know the CPU usage over a given period, not over the whole process lifetime. :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at htop, you can configure quite a lot with it.

Comment: unfortunately it cannot split the cpu on user/system/wait time for a specific thread - only for the whole machine

Comment: Yes, but how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried sar? It can fetch a lot of information even on pid level.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios and PNP http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.4/start

Works awesome... little configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled on this on a embedded system where we don't have the fancy tools to look in to this stuff.

For this, I have used `cpuacct cgroup` and placed each thread into its own folder. This way I was able to measure their usage.

Hierarchy was looking like this:

```
my-app.service
|-tid1
|-tid2
|-tid3
```

Then I changed it to

```
my-app.service
|-dir1
|  -tid1
|-dir2
|  -tid2
|-dir3
|  -tid3
```